# Should Parent or Module projects have svn trunk-branch-tag structure?

Tags: java, maven, svn, project

I have 2 different projects that share some common code. Therefore I'm about to create a Multi Module Maven project.

```
ParentModuleProject
-webModule
--common
--Module1
--Module2

-importerModule
--common
--Module1
--Module2
```

The applications `Module1` and `Module2` will have their own release cycles. They will not necessarily be released together. Also they will run on different servers. The `common` modules are just utility modules that share common code between all modules (like domain logic). They will never be released for themself.

Also the importer projects will define some batch jobs, and each batch job for each module will run on a different server.
So all in all I will have 4 servers with 2x2 similar applications, but which will all have their own lifecycle. But they will share lots of code throught the `common` module.

Question: which of the project would make sense to have trunk/tags/branches svn structure?
Only the submodules itself? Or would it also be useful later to have `webModule`, `importerModule` or even the root `ParentModuleProject` to have this structure?

When would this be useful? If I'd like to make tags/branches of all the modules contained in one tag? If so, and if all my modules have their own lifecycle, this will probably never be the case, so I can omit this svn structure in the 3 parent modules?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you mentioned common modules are utlity modules which will never going to get released so creating branch/tag/trunk folder for it will be of no use.

Since **importerModule/Module1** , **importerModule/Module2** ,  **webModule/Module1** and **webModule/Module2** have independent release cycle there is be a need of seprate Tag Trunk and Branch folder for them .

As SVN provides flexiblity to choose the way to maintain folder structure there can be many ways to handle the requirement but I like the following one:

**Layout**

Where webModule and importerModule will have the tag/trunk/branch structure.

> --**ParentModuleProject**
>
> ---**webModule**
>
> -----**Trunk**
>
> ------- *common*
>
> ------- *Module1*
>
> ------- *Module2*
>
> -----**Branches**
>
> ------- *Module1-R1*
>
> ------- *Module2-R3*
>
> -----**Tags**
>
> ------- *Module1-R1-1.0-120413*
>
> ------- Module2-R2-2.0-200313
>
> ---**importerModule**
>
> -----**Trunk**
>
> ------- *common*
>
> ------- *Module1*
>
> ------- *Module2*
>
> -----**Branches**
>
> ------- *Module1-R6*
>
> ------- *Module2-R8*
>
> -----**Tags**
>
> ------- *Module1-R5-1.0-120413*
>
> ------- Module2-R7-2.0-200313

By using this layout you dnt have to manage seprate tag , trunk and branch folder for each module.

As the trunk will be contain the key components of you application webModule and importerModule and you can easily create release branches out of it for Module1 and Module2 like

> svn copy "^/webmodule/trunk/module1" "^/webmodule/branches/module1-r1".

Seprate release branches of Module1 and Module2 will handle the different release cycles.

Since tag is just a snapshot of what you released keeping the tags of Module1 and Module2 together will not be an issue like

> svn copy "^/webmodule/branches/module1-r1" "^/webmodule/tags/module1-r1-230413"

Hope this helps

Jyotsna

Comment: Thanks, that looks promising. Can I also this way use SVN plugin in eclipse to rightclick on a module > create tag? Will that work if the modules itself don't contain a trunk/tag/branch structure, but are themselves contained in one as you suggested?

Comment: And regarding the example: would `webModule` and `importerModule` be "real" maven modules, or simple flat folders?

Comment: Yes you can create tags while using eclipse which is integrated with SVN via SVN plugin (https://www.eclipse.org/subversive/documentation/teamSupport/SVNaction/tag.php) http://help.collab.net/index.jsp?topic=/org.tigris.subclipse.doc/topics/toc.html . The thing which needs to be done carefully is the location where you are creating your tags. It can surely work with the above mentioned way as tag/branches/trunk is just folders in SVN its all upto us how we want to use it efficently. :)

Comment: They can be real Maven project since you can configure it as multi-module project while buildling. You can configure Master pom in the webModule and importerModule folder and child project like Module1 and Module2 will have seprate application specific pom .